# Swal inside a Swal - Second swal closes both(Is this the expected behavior?)

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

I have a scenario where i have a first swal, that allows opening a second swal.

When closing the second swal (by OK or cancel), both the second and the first swal are closed.

Is this the expected behavior? I was expecting that when closing the second swal, the first one would remain open until explicitly closed (by OK or cancel).

```js
const html = "<a onclick='swal(\"Second swal\")'>Open second swal</a>";
swal({
    title: "swal 1",
    html: html,
    showCancelButton: true,
    allowOutsideClick: false,
    customClass: 'swal-wide',
}).then(function(value) {
    },
    function(dismiss) {
    }
).catch(swal.noop);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.13.1/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
```

Comment: FYI -- we have our own equivalent to JSFiddle called "StackSnippets". See https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 1):

According to a sweet alert developer: "There can be only one swal instance at a time. Each call of swal() removes the current modal and makes a new one."